# Changing color of single cell in Table

Tags: html, css, quasar-framework

Is there a way to change the color of single cell in the table? I want to create checkered pattern in the table so that every even cell has different color as well as every even column has different.

I only managed to change the color of all cells in a row:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #FA8072;
}
```

But not sure how I could apply it to get result like this:

[image]

Here you can see my attempt in codepen:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/pokepim/pen/JjdBpzJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to select odd and even tr but also td :

example:

```css
td {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, lightgreen, lightgreen, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), lightgreen, lightgreen) lightgreen;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #FA8072, #FA8072, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), #FA8072, #FA8072) #FA8072;
}
```

```html
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <div class="q-table__container q-table--horizontal-separator column no-wrap q-table__card q-table--no-wrap">
      <div class="q-table__middle scroll">
        <table class="q-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-left bg-primary text-white bg-primary text-white">Confusion Matrix</th>
              <th class="text-center">Actual 1</th>
              <th class="text-center">Actual 0</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="">
              <th class="text-left bg-grey-2 ellipsis" style="max-width: 50px;">Predicted 1</th>
              <td class="text-center">2</td>
              <td class="text-center">2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <th class="text-left bg-grey-2 ellipsis" style="max-width: 50px;">Predicted 0</th>
              <td class="text-center">23</td>
              <td class="text-center">12</td>
            </tr>
              <tr class="">
              <th class="text-left bg-grey-2 ellipsis" style="max-width: 50px;">Predicted 1</th>
              <td class="text-center">2</td>
              <td class="text-center">2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
              <th class="text-left bg-grey-2 ellipsis" style="max-width: 50px;">Predicted 0</th>
              <td class="text-center">23</td>
              <td class="text-center">12</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It kind of gets it done, however I wonder why it only works with gradient not with normal colors?

Comment: @AlexT is should work with any background rules , a typo or a specifity selector matter  maybe ?

Comment: Somehow the cells do not behave like that, the color do not change: https://codepen.io/pokepim/pen/JjdBpzJ

Comment: @AlexT if you increase the specifity: `.q-pa-md td {
  background: green;
}` it works ;) Note that : `tr:nth-child(1n) td` is enough.